# Refactored submit event failing

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which works as expected

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    wikiViewer.eventActionTrigger();
    wikiViewer.spinner("on");
  });
```

While refactoring it to

```
this.eventFunc("form","submit",setOfActionBeta);
```

Jquery Ajax request that it triggers fails

Here is the full codepen

[codepen](http://codepen.io/nicc/pen/QvbGZy)

Comment: Too much code in demo - so it's hard to find the problem there. Not enough code in question - so it's not clear what the problem is.